Synchronization of progress bar
I am trying to introduce and synchronize a progress bar in an R Shiny app. This is a chunk from the main server function:
# Simulation Logic
observeEvent(input$calc_tax_prop_Button, {
  progress <- shiny::Progress$new()
  on.exit(progress$close())

  progress$set(message = "Running Simulation", detail = "Please wait...", value = 0)

  # Continuous back-and-forth movement of progress bar
  for (i in 1:10) {
    for (j in seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)) {
      progress$set(value = j)
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
    }
    for (j in seq(1, 0, by = -0.1)) {
      progress$set(value = j)
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
    }
  }

  # Actual script execution
  source("./Scripts/Scenarios.R")  # ←- Other script to execute 
  showNotification("Simulation is done!", duration = NULL)
})

When I press the button which activates this code, I face a problem. Namely, I can see the progress indicator as shown below, but the issue is that the part for calling other scripts (source("./Scripts/Scenarios.R")) is not activated.

To summarize, the progress bar goes back and forth but is not connected with the activation of this line: source("./Scripts/Scenarios.R").
Namely, when I press the button which activates this code, I want to see the progress indicator moving back and forth until this line (source("./Scripts/Scenarios.R")) finishes executing. At the end, I want to see the notification showNotification("Simulation is done!", duration = NULL).
Can anybody please help me solve this problem?

source() is outside of the for loop so it's unsurprising that it's not being executed during the progression of the indicator.

Somehow it seems to me that the problem is in the parallel execution of both tasks at the same time. First one is executed and then the second.

I dont think I've ever seen, nor would I want to see, a softwares progress bar seeming to reverse on me...  Are you making some sort of confrontational art piece intended to shock and disturb the software using community ? :-P

Let's focus on the essence. The progress bar is not synchronized with the code. This is the main issue. I think the picture clearly captures the context.

Progress bars are used to track progress ; if your intent is to track your progress through ./Scripts/Scenarios.R you will need to open up ./Scripts/Scenarios.R and provide updates from there. You can not wrap a black box function, and magically understand its progress. Or are you trying to fake it ? you have an expectation that the black box should take x time, and you want to asynchronously accompany that time with a very abritrary progress bar ?

How to track progress from ./Scripts/Scenarios.R  ? Any suggestions ?

you need to understand the content of your script (which you havent shared) and understand how you would measure progress within it.

@Nir Graham. Too much theory for nothing. If you think you know where the problem is, please offer a solution. Otherwise, your advice is not very useful for the post.

The issue is, that R is single threaded. You could run your simulation in a background process to unblock your UI e.g. via a ExtendedTask. Another option is using library(ipc)s AsyncProgress.
